# How can I reload or refresh the ngx-gallery thumbnail images after I modify the image array?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-gallery

I'm using [ngx-gallery](https://github.com/lukasz-galka/ngx-gallery) to display images.
I want to reload the images or have them refreshed in the thumbnail gallery, main image and full page image when I modify the order (ex. swap image 1 and 3 in the image array)

**Problem** - I can't figure out how to reload/reset/rerender/refresh the thumbnail gallery.
If there isn't a ngx-gallery way to do it, maybe there is a typescript way?

Here is what I've tried so far

```
<ngx-gallery #gallery [options]="galleryOptions" [images]="galleryImages"></ngx-gallery>
```

In my .ts file

1. set images to null then replaced the images:

   this.galleryImages = null;

   this.galleryImages = this.memberService.member.photos;
2. used the show(0) method from the documentation - displayed image 0 but didn't rearrange order in the thumbnail gallery

   @ViewChild('gallery') gallery: NgxGalleryComponent;

   this.gallery.show(0);
3. I also tried

   this.gallery.thubmnails.reset(1);

   this.gallery.thubmnails.reset(0);

   this.gallery.ngOnInit();

**Update** - I found the thumbnail property inside the component, so I can change the thumbnail ordering, but can't still find a way to alter the main image ordering.

Here is what I did to alter the thumbnail ordering

```
[this.gallery.thubmnails.images[index], this.gallery.thubmnails.images[0]]
    = [this.gallery.thubmnails.images[0], this.gallery.thubmnails.images[index]];
```

but this doesn't change the order of the other images and when I tried to use the same approach it didn't work for the bigger (full page, page) images.

**Update2** I used an interval to provide a work around and get it to do what I wanted. After I reordered 'this.memberService.member.photos', I cleared out the array then reset it with values. Without the interval it doesn't work.

```
[this.memberService.member.photos[index], this.memberService.member.photos[0]]
    = [this.memberService.member.photos[0], this.memberService.member.photos[index]];
this.galleryImages = [];
setInterval(() => {
  this.galleryImages = this.memberService.member.photos;
}, 0);
```